# facing difficulty to download gradle in dolphin android version

Tags: java, android, gradle

After installing the new windows10 i am facing issue with newer version of android studio dolphin everytime when I open android studio with a new project or an existing project it starts downloading the gradle 7.4 and after sometime i got an error of timeout. I tried a method found on youtube where the gradle wrapper properties are replaced but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced some difficulties too when I was updating android studio to dolphin version.

- Go to gradle-wrapper.properties and try to change distributionUrl value to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
- Go to the project structure and change gradle version to 7.4

Comment: tried both still facing error       can you tell me what shoud be the android gradle plugin version with gradle version 7.4